# How to create pdt handler in paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I try to create pdt handler in sandbox in paypal. But when I try to go profile tab it always return empty page. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try in different web browsers by clearing cookies and cache. If you are still persisting the same issue, kindly file a PayPal MTS ticket at : https://www.paypal-techsupport.com . Then you will get assistance from PayPal MTS team.